# Connected devices to router are hidden

Tags: router, network-scanners

I was scanning devices connected to my WiFi with netdiscover

```
netdiscover -r 192.168.31.0/24
```

I was unable to find any device. I only get router's IP and MAC address.
It does not show any device even though I have connected 2 PCs and 2 Android phones.

My router is xiaomi 3c router.

Can anybody tell me why devices are not visible?

I can see all devices through the router page but not by a network scanning tool.

[I can see devices when connected to my Android hotspot scanning through netdiscover]

Comment: Are clients isolated by the router? .........how to remove isolation and how to check it is isolated or not.

Comment: Try http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/arpscan/
see what this tool shows.

Comment: I used arp -a before same result. I think router have some setting which hides the devices.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. Was able to get the connected devices on mobile hotspot but not on a router.

Sometimes netdiscover ARP packets timeout in real networks which is very common, Hence, to increase the number of packets sent for scanning, use the following command:

```
netdiscover -c 10 -r ip_range -i interface-name
```

This worked for me.